# Cucumber with table definitions and test/seed data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I have a scenario like this:

```
Scenario:  Display some articles
  Given the following article pages:
    | title | body        |
    | test  | hello world |
```

I have seen some people create xxx_steps.rb and then generate the data on the fly.

When cucumber runs, does it run by default with RAILS_ENV=test?  Will it load seeds.rb for each run with a fresh test db?  If not, how can I make it so it does?

Also, does cucumber load all the files in /step_definitions or is there some sort of convention that it loads any files that match the current feature file?

Answer (score 1):

To generate data on the fly I would advise you to use the factory_girl gem.
You can generate fields automatically while having control about others.

In this case I have two Arrays of names (first_names and last_names) and I will randomly create Contact objects.

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :contact do
    name {"#{first_names.sample} #{last_names.sample}"}
    email  {"#{name.downcase.gsub!(' ', '.')}@example.com"}
    vat_number {rand(9999999).to_s.center(7, rand(9).to_s)}
    gender {['male', 'female'].sample}
    birth_date {Date.today - rand(200..40000)}
  end
end
```

Then to create an contact I just need FactoryGirl.create(:contact) for a single record.
You can adapt this example to fit your needs.

In your case, you can use your table like this:

```
Given /^the following article pages:$/ do |table|
   table.hashes.each do |hash|
   FactoryGirl.create(:article, hash
end
```